# Swft iOS How can I get the size of external framework (Cocoapod package)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, size

The source size of the framework from pods/xxx seems like not the final size of the binary build. Is there any method to retrieve / check the build-binary framework size that installed via Cocoapod?

Answer (score 0):

The tool [cocoapods-size](https://github.com/google/cocoapods-size) (by google) does exactly that.